# Updates install error

Tags: updates, error-handling

When attempting to install any updates via Update Manager, I received this error message:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

I attempted to use the terminal but could not find the right command. Any ideas?

I ran the command: `dpkg --configure -a` and got this message back:

```
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
```

I'm running `Linux Mint 18.1` "Serena".

Comment: Can you check free space first on your file system? In terminal: `df -h`

Comment: What would I be looking for?

Comment: Mint is not an official Ubuntu flavor. Please ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: You need find line with `/' at end in result table. And left at this symbol you will see % value, For example `/dev/sda1  232G   81G  139G  37% /` Available free space in this case 100%-**37%** =63% . I want to check is your File System have a free space and this value <100%.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely <100%. I believe I still have 35%.

Answer (score 1):

In  your terminal type:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Copy any errors that appear with your mouse and post them into your question.

If no errors then try your original command again.

---

From Linux Mint forums this answer: [Re: _cache->open failed. Cannot update.](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=74524)

> Worked for me!
>
> For everyone else who comes later the command to fix this issue is:
>
> ```
> sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
> ```

Comment: I ran this but when trying to update I am still getting same error message.

Comment: @KevinCascell Sorry I was half-asleep. Ive changed the answer to read: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Ran it and got a long message: